# standalone = yes does not appear in xml generated using moxy implementation of jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have a xml file generated using jaxb. However standalone = yes does not appear in the xml document. Is there a problem.

The code used is

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
Marshaller marshall = context.createMarshaller();
marshall.setProperty(JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshall.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, schema_location);
marshall.marshal(object, outputstream);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Duplicate of

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260436/standalone-value-does-not-appear-in-xml-generated-by-moxy-jaxb

Comment: I found the answer in the below link

[jaxb standalone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260436/standalone-value-does-not-appear-in-xml-generated-by-moxy-jaxb