# standalone value does not appear in xml generated by moxy - jaxb

Tags: xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have a xml file generated using moxy implementation of jaxb. However standalone value does not appear in the xml document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The `standalone` attribute is seldom used, and is only relevant if you are using a DTD.  Since JAXB (JSR-222) is primarily used with XML Schema it doesn't apply.  We chose not to output that attribute in the MOXy implemenation of JAXB (JSR-222).

Other XML technologies chose not to support the standalone attribute as well.  For example I am not aware of a way to output a standalone value using a StAX parser.

**For More Information**

- http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlquotations/standalone